# Django rest project dockerfile

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, dockerfile

I am absolutely new to docker. I have an existing Django Rest project whose structure looks like following:

[image]

My requirements.txt:

```
django==1.8.8
djangorestframework
markdown
django-filter
django-rest-auth       
django-cors-headers
django-secure
django-sslserver
django-rest-auth[extras]
```

Normally I create a virtual env > activate it >  do `pip install requirements.txt` and additionally I need `easy_install mysql-python` to get started.

I want to dockerize this project. Can someone help me build a simple docker file this project?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/
This link contains some simple examples, you can add to it as you need more stuff installed.
Anything you would run in the command line, you can run with this dockerfile with the RUN keyword.

Comment: Hey @Nitish I was wondering, was my answer helpful?

Comment: Honestly, I caught up with some other work and could not finish this docker file..but I will take a look again

Comment: Ok @Nitish let me now :)

Answer (score 2):

As @DriesDeRydt suggest in his comment, in the provided [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components) there is a very simple example of a docker file which installs requirements:

> Add the following content to the Dockerfile.
>
> ```
> FROM python:2.7  
> ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1  
> RUN mkdir /code  
> WORKDIR /code  
> ADD requirements.txt /code/  
> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
> ADD . /code/
> ```
>
> This Dockerfile starts with a Python 2.7 base image. The base image is
>   modified by adding a new code directory. The base image is further
>   modified by installing the Python requirements defined in the
>   requirements.txt file.

You can change the image to fit your needed python version, by pulling the needed [python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/). For example:

`FROM python:2.7` change to `FROM python:3.5` or `FROM python:latest`

But as the above Dockerfile stands and assuming that you will place it inside the `server` folder, it will work for a test case.

Here is the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for further reading.